# Is there a way to change Adam to legacy when using Mac M1/M2 in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I am running a Deep Learning model, but sometimes I use my work PC and sometimes my Mac. The problem is that whenever using the Mac (with an M2 chip), I get this warning message:

> WARNING:absl: At this time, the v2.11+ optimizer `tf.keras.optimizers.Adam` runs slowly on M1/M2 Macs, please use the legacy Keras optimizer instead, located at `tf.keras.optimizers.legacy.Adam`.

I question whether there is a way to shift to `tf.keras.optimizers.legacy.Adam` in my Mac. As a side question, is it beneficial at all? I guess so because my training is taking way more than I expected, given the problem's simplicity.

As a minimum viable example, please check this example I adapted from the [TensorFlow website](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/quickstart/beginner):

```py
import tensorflow as tf

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
])

loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)

# If-else should go here:

# If in a Mac with M1 / M2:
# opt = tf.keras.optimizers.legacy.Adam(learning_rate=0.0005)

# Else:
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0005)

model.compile(optimizer=opt,
              loss=loss_fn,
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5)
```

Thanks in advance, and apologies if this has been already answered. I could not find a question similar.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I found a way to solve my first problem by looking at the [keras optimizer code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/v2.14.0/keras/optimizers/optimizer.py).

An example of the solution is below:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import platform

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
])

loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)

if platform.system() == "Darwin" and platform.processor() == "arm":
    opt = tf.keras.optimizers.legacy.Adam(learning_rate=0.0005)
else:
    opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0005)

model.compile(optimizer=opt,
              loss=loss_fn,
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5)
```

The way I solved it:

1. I found in the code where it threw the error (Line 69 in the code [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/v2.14.0/keras/optimizers/optimizer.py), as of Oct 03, 2023):

> `if platform.system() == "Darwin" and platform.processor() == "arm":`

2. To do so, it needs the `platform` module. I imported it in the second line of my MVE above.
3. Then, I added the optimizer to match the desired condition.

I hope this helps.